# SSRS Expressions query - SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder

I am creating a table and I am doing a custom count for each of the columns to say how many times the value was used, I am using the formula below and it is working

```vb
=Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!erromsg.Value.Contains("1.5"), 1, 0))
```

The column I am having a problem with is where I want it to do a sum for values that DO NOT contain the any of the numbers e.g.

```vb
=Sum(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!erromsg.Value.NOTContains("1.5","1.6"), 1, 0))
```

I am guessing the `NOTContains` is not correct and need to identify the correct command and also I am not sure if the multiple option is in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

For not contains you can use the following Iif expression

```
=SUM(
    Iif(
        Fields!errormessage.Value.Contains("1.5") OR
        Fields!errormessage.Value.Contains("1.6"), 
        0,
        1
    )
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: your a genius!

Thank you very much for your help. Have a great day!